# Why is fuelphp generating incorrect queries

Tags: php, mysql, fuelphp

I'm trying to generate a database query using fuelphp.

```
 $query = DB::query("SELECT LCASE(:field) FROM :table WHERE :field = :val AND 'id' != :id");

 $query->bind('field',$field);
 $query->bind('table',$table);
 $query->bind('val',$val);
 $query->bind('id',$id);

 $result = $query->execute();
```

My code returns this mysql query:

```
SELECT LCASE('short_code') FROM 'events' WHERE 'short_code' = 'uvt2015' AND 'id' != '0`
```

which gives me this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'events' WHERE 'short_code' = 'uvt2015' AND 'id' != '0'
```

When I replace the single quotes around the column names I get this query which gives me the results I want.

```
SELECT LCASE(`short_code`) FROM `events` WHERE `short_code` = 'uvt2015' AND `id` != '0'
```

Why is it that fuelphp generates queries with the wrong quotes? I suspect this might be an error related to the versions of my fuelphp/php/mysql.

- PHP version: 5.5.12
- MySQL version: 5.6.17
- FuelPHP version: 1.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not bind the table name as a parameter in prepared statement. It will be handled as a string and so there are single quotes arround this name.

you have to use :

```
$query = DB::query("SELECT LCASE($field) FROM `$table` WHERE $field = :val AND 'id' != :id");
```

Comment: So the full query should be:
$query = DB::query("SELECT LCASE(`$field`) FROM `$table` WHERE `$field` = :val AND `id` != :id"); ?

Comment: For future newbie visitors: Just be sure to take care of sanitizing/escaping `$table` and `$field`, if it's from user input (which is not necessary with parameters added with `->bind`).